# Samsung galaxy note 3 root void warranty

Tags: custom-roms, root-access, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have read several articles pertaining to rooting a Note 3 and voiding it's warranty.  I know a custom rom, or custom rom app would change the binary counter.  Would I be safe rooting and using Titanium backup or similar to remove / freeze samsung bloatware?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No in fact there's the `Knox void warranty` flag that will be set to `0x1` if you are on the 4.3.

Knox is not yet really understanded but so far something is sure, if you flash any rom that does not contains the knox security (official or not official) it will void your warranty.

So even if you flash a 4.2.2 version of stock rom from samsung it will set the knox void warranty to 0x1 and your phone will not be supported by Samsung.

**Edit 1** : Well according to comment, it might be possible to avoid the change of th knox flag, with the root method from root de la vega. But still if you are in USA (where voiding warranty with a simple logical flag is possible) be carefull while proceding because it still tricky.

Souce:
[xda forum about Knox behaviour](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2447832)

Comment: Just to add on this, many people on XDA have actually gotten a service from Samsung, and their support are giving very dispirate answers on the issue, despite tripping the Knox flag. There is a method to root it without tripping knox, but any custom kernel/firmware will trip it to 0x1 immediately. However, I find it is best to assume that once you root you lose warranty. Here's the "Knox Friendly Root" http://www.xda-developers.com/android/knox-friendly-root-for-multiple-galaxy-note-3-variants/   So the OP could root it and use TB to freeze bloatware in theory, but it COULD trip still.

Comment: Well thank you for the knox friendly method, I wasn't aware.

Comment: My pleasure! Knox is a pain in my side, so anything to get around it makes me happy! It's worth nothing that a few people who had their devices repaired by Samsung got them back with Knox back to 0x0! That is without any motherboards etc being replaced. It seems not to be an eFuse but any answer to fixing it / changing it is still up in the air!

Comment: It looks like de la vega would work for my Tmobile Note 3  according to this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2481330&page=2